# rpi lirc_rpi in and outputs wrong

Tags: gpio, lirc

i just started using lirc on raspberry 3. with

```
sudo apt-get install lirc
```

i put on the rpi, i changed the entries in

```
modules
hardware.conf
config.txt
```

as stated in http://alexba.in/blog/2013/01/06/setting-up-lirc-on-the-raspberrypi/

but **i dont get any in- and out-pins associated with lirc**. these are my outputs:

*uname -a*

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.16-v7+ #899 SMP Thu Jul 28 12:40:33 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

*cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio*

```
GPIOs 0-53, platform/3f200000.gpio, pinctrl-bcm2835:

GPIOs 100-101, platform/soc:virtgpio, brcmvirt-gpio, can sleep:
gpio-100 (                    |?                   ) out hi
```

*sudo dmesg | grep lirc*

```
[3.662057] lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 245 
[4.659023] lirc_rpi: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[5.618718] lirc_rpi: auto-detected active high receiver on GPIO pin 18
[5.619407] lirc_rpi lirc_rpi: lirc_dev: driver lirc_rpi registered at minor = 0
[5.619411] lirc_rpi: driver registered!
```

- i thought, the standard config would do me in and out on GPIO17 and 18. instead of it i've got only a virtual pin.
- possible hint: i use a python-script on startup with GPIO-Usage (physical Buttons) - disabled on startup for now.
- **how to get "real" connections for lirc?**

Comment: I don't know anything about `lirc` but I do know that using 3 year old tutorials written for an obsolete OS which predates `systemd` and `Device Tree` isn't going to work. Try some more research based on current OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore all those outdated instructions and **UNDO** any changes you made.

Add the following to `/boot/config.txt` and reboot.

`dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=17,gpio_in_pin=18`

For general device tree help see `/boot/overlays/README`.

In future make sure you are using an up to date tutorial as things change quite quickly on the Pi.

Comment: thanks for the advice. but it didnt changed anything. only this one virtual lirc-connection on gpio-100.
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50873/lirc-wont-transmit-irsend-hardware-does-not-support-sending
i tested these informations as well - and theyre not that far from old blog-entries.

Comment: As long as you have done what was suggested then LIRC should work.  Time to double check your hardware and wiring.  Perhaps add a photo to your question.

Comment: after testing the lirc-input (although it wasnt listed in _cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio_, that was my main question above) -> it works, maybe it worked before (i only tested the output-gpio)