# LIRC remote control won't send (irsend: hardware does not support sending)

Tags: gpio, modules, lirc

I'm trying to build a TV remote control using Raspberry Pi, and I get the following error when I try to send a command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ irsend SEND_ONCE Samsung_BN59-00937A KEY_POWER

irsend: command failed: SEND_ONCE Samsung_BN59-00937A KEY_POWER    
irsend: hardware does not support sending
```

I've built an IR circuit, which works fine when I test it using a simple blinking script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
print "Starting blink test.."
GPIO.setwarnings(True)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    GPIO.output(17, True)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(17, False)
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run this I can see the IR LED blinking using a camera LCD viewfinder. The circuit is wired according to [this tutorial](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2015/10/Raspberry-Pi-IR-remote#article_l1).

I set up LIRC following [this tutorial](http://alexba.in/blog/2013/01/06/setting-up-lirc-on-the-raspberrypi/).

My /etc/modules has these two lines in it:

```
lirc_dev
lirc_rpi gpio_in_pin=18 gpio_out_pin=17
```

My /boot/config.txt has this line in it:

```
dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_in_pin=18,gpio_out_pin=17
```

My /etc/lirc/hardware.conf looks like this:

```
# /etc/lirc/hardware.conf
#
# Arguments which will be used when launching lircd
LIRCD_ARGS="--uinput"

#Don't start lircmd even if there seems to be a good config file
#START_LIRCMD=false

#Don't start irexec, even if a good config file seems to exist.
#START_IREXEC=false

#Try to load appropriate kernel modules
LOAD_MODULES=true

# Run "lircd --driver=help" for a list of supported drivers.
DRIVER="default"
# usually /dev/lirc0 is the correct setting for systems using udev
DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
MODULES="lirc_rpi"

# Default configuration files for your hardware if any
LIRCD_CONF=""
LIRCMD_CONF=""
```

My /etc/rc.local has this line in it:

```
modprobe lirc_rpi gpio_in_pin=18 gpio_out_pins=17
```

I also tried following the suggested answer from this question and added the file

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ir-remote.conf
```

with this line in it:

```
options lirc_rpi gpio_in_pin=18 gpio_out_pin=17
```

But I still get the same error with irsend. Please could somebody help me fix this? Thank you.

EDIT: This is the output of lsmod when I remove the lirc lines from /etc/modules, /etc/rc.local, and /etc/modprobe.d/ir-remote.conf:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   10340  2 
hci_uart               17943  1 
btbcm                   5929  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             326105  22 bnep,btbcm,hci_uart
brcmfmac              186403  0 
brcmutil                5661  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              427855  1 brcmfmac
rfkill                 16037  4 cfg80211,bluetooth
snd_bcm2835            20447  1 
snd_pcm                75762  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              19288  1 snd_pcm
snd                    51908  5 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
bcm2835_gpiomem         3040  0 
bcm2835_wdt             3225  0 
lirc_rpi                6478  0 
uio_pdrv_genirq         3164  0 
uio                     8000  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
lirc_dev                8310  1 lirc_rpi
rc_core                16468  1 lirc_dev
i2c_dev                 5859  0 
fuse                   84037  3 
ipv6                  347594  46
```

Comment: You should be using device tree so delete the lirc lines from `/etc/modules`, `/etc/rc.local`, and `/etc/modprobe.d/ir-remote.conf`.  Then reboot and add the output of `lsmod` to your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I removed the lines from the three files and added the output of `lsmod`.

Comment: Okay.  I added the device tree entry, installed lirc, used your hardware.conf and downloaded a Samsung config file from LIRC home.  It works for me.  Sorry.  Don't know what's wrong with your set up.

Comment: Please could you explain how you added the device tree entry? I'm relatively new to this, and I could have done something wrong.

Comment: I just mean I added the line `dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_in_pin=18,gpio_out_pin=17` to `/boot/config.txt` and rebooted.

Comment: You can take a look at this answer: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/60899/60597

Comment: I created an extensive [tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70945/setting-up-a-remote-control-using-lirc) on stackexchange on how I managed to remote control my TV using only a Raspberry Pi and an old Infrared diode from an old remote control.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that the service is starting correctly via

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lirc status
```

A common cause is a bad lircd.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some initial tricks in http://martinho.comuf.com.

But be attention on "**UNCONFIGURED**" lines in config files.

As I wrote there You have to remove all lines with word "UNCONFIGURED" in /etc/init.d/lirc

I don´t know why but a script look for that word even as comment.

Make backup of files before edit and dont´t forget to reboot after changes.

---I´m using a Raspberry PI3---

Comment: It would be nice to mention the page you link to isn't in English.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this forum post: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191425#p1213186

It mentions version 0.9.4 of lircd has a new config file format which is incompatible with the old, and that there is an included script (`/usr/share/lirc/lirc-old2new`) you can run which fixes it all up.

Solved my problem.

Comment: This solution is actualy working with Raspberry 3 B+ and LIRC 0.9.4 !