# How to pass parameters to program run from init.d?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, lirc, init.d

I'm debugging lirc on a Pi 3b running Stretch with 4.19 kernel.

In my [previous question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108001/lirc-wont-irsend-special-command-required-why/108005#108005), I found a way to cause lircd to function, but it requires invoking the daemon with passed parameters.

I need to start lircd like this:

```
sudo lircd --device /dev/lirc0
```

Now I want to cause the Pi to boot with lirc in a usable state, using those required parameters in init.d.

The "start-stop-daemon" section of the file "lircd" in /etc/init.d looks like this:

```
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo \
                --exec /usr/sbin/lircd -- < /dev/null
```

When the Pi boots, lircd is already running, so to allow irsend to function I have to issue these commands to kill and restart with the required parameters:

```
sudo pkill -SIGTERM  lircd
sudo lircd --device /dev/lirc0
```

The [Man page for start-stop-daemon](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) --start says:

"Any arguments given after -- on the command line are passed unmodified to the program being started."

I edited the "start-stop-daemon" line of the "start" case section in the file "lircd" in /etc/init.d to this:

```
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo \
                --exec /usr/sbin/lircd  -- --device /dev/lirc0 < /dev/null
```

Based on the Man page for start-stop-daemon, I'm interpreting this command in its unmodified state as passing "< /dev/null" to lircd when it is run. That is the string that is after "--".

My expectation is that after my edit, the string "--device /dev/lirc0 < /dev/null" will be passed as parameters to /usr/sbin/lircd when it is run.

However, it does not work. irsend does not function at startup, until the kill and re-run commands are given.  I'm assuming the parameters are not passed to lircd, but I'm not sure why.

I am not sure why the original parameters after "--" redirect /dev/null to stdin. Why is that needed? Maybe that is sending my added parameters to /dev/null too? 
What would be the proper syntax to pass the required parameters?

Answer (score 2):

The IO redirection is not a argument. You can see that with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while [ "$1" != "" ] ; do
    i=$((i+1))
    echo "$i:  $1"
    shift
done
```

If you execute this with `./script a b </dev/null`, the output will be

```
a
b
```

So the shell that executes the script does the IO redirection for `start-stop-daemon`.

If you put quotes around the `</dev/null`, it will be passed as a argument. But then, `start-stop-daemon` will also pass it to `lircd` as a argument and not as an IO redirection.

The question is: why do you need a `</dev/null` when you start-up `lircd`? I have never needed to do that.

Comment: I have no idea why </dev/null  is needed. It was put there by the installer for lirc.  I left it because I didn't understand why it was needed either, but it must be for a reason? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are using Raspbian Stretch that already comes with **systemd** that replaces the old style **SysV** init system, managed with files in `/etc/init.d/`. This is deprecated since years and only emulated by systemd to ensure limited downstream compatibility. Have a look at [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/).

That you run into problems with sophisticated modifications of init scripts is not a surprise. You should really consider to use Unit files from systemd to manage services. If you really want to continue with init scripts then you should look at [man systemd-sysv-generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sysv-generator.html) what it does with your init scripts and why it doesn't work as expected.